# コンパイル時にエラーが発生します。 flutter、firebaseアプリ（Android Studioで開発）

Tags: android-studio, firebase, gradle

アプリをRunで起動すると、下記のようなエラーが出ます。

●エラー内容

> Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
>   Initializing gradle...
>   Resolving dependencies...
>   Finished with error: Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
>
> Error running Gradle:
>   ProcessException: Process "C:\Users\\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app2\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:
>   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where:
>     Build file 'C:\Users\\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app2\android\build.gradle' > line: 24
> - What went wrong:
>     A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
>     A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>     Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:classpath'.
>     Cannot resolve external dependency com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1 because no repositories are defined.
>         Required by:
>             project :app
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 1s
>   Command: C:\Users\\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app2\android\gradlew.bat app:properties

build.gradleファイル内に、下記の内容を記載しない場合はエラーは発生しないので、この部分がエラーの原因と思われますが、対応方法などご教授いただけると大変助かります。

```
buildscript {
dependencies {
    // Add this line
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    }
}
allprojects {
    // ...
    repositories {
        google() // Google's Maven repository
        // ...
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    // ...
}

dependencies {
    // ...
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    // Getting a "Could not find" error? Make sure you have
    // added the Google maven respository to your root build.gradle
}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

●build.gradleファイル内容

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutt    er.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.andro    id.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.androidstudio.flutter_app2"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunne    r"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` w    orks.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3    .0.2'
}


buildscript {
    dependencies {
        // Add this line
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    }
}
allprojects {
    // ...
    repositories {
        google() // Google's Maven repository
        // ...
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    // ...
}

dependencies {
    // ...
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    // Getting a "Could not find" error? Make sure you have
    // added the Google maven respository to your root build.gradle
}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/183014

Comment: リンク有難うございます。リンク先で解決いたしました。

Answer (score 1):

プロジェクト単位のbuild.gradleとアプリ単位のbuild.gradleの切り分けができていませんでした。
それぞれ、該当のファイルに書き直したところ、エラーは発生しなくなりました。
https://teratail.com/questions/183014